# TabLayout goes under the content of Framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport

I have a FrameLayout that includes a TabLayout and a ViewPager inside it. Obviously the ViewPager loads a fragment. Now the problem is that TabLayout goes  under the content of fragment when it's loaded and therefore disappears.

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </FrameLayout>
```

How do I fix it?

EDIT:

using the following code I was able to make it work but now the tabs are always stuck to the top when scrolling... anyway to fix that?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should Use a linear layout or switch the 2 children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to a vertical `LinearLayout`. Then the `ViewPager` will appear beneath the `TabLayout` instead of drawing over it.

Comment: Using `LinearLayout` causes the whole thing to disappear. could you provide a code??

Comment: OK. fixed it.... But TabLayout is now stuck at the top when scrolling... any way to fix that?

Comment: The typical design pattern is to have the tabs stay at the top, but is your `ScrollView` inside one of the `ViewPager` `Fragments'?

Comment: Oh... I get it. Yes, the fragment is a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

`FrameLayout` actually stacks all of its children on top of each other. So in your case this isn't a desired behavior. You should consider using a vertical `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LinearLayout with orientation of 'vertical' instead of a FrameLayout. A FrameLayout is generally used when you want to contain a single child (such as a fragment).